# Masking the actual page url using PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to cover the actual page URL? Let say:

http://www.samplesite.com/post.php?title=sample-title

to

http://www.samplesite.com/sample-title

Comment: oh sorry let me check the page thank you

Comment: yeah it is the answer I am looking for thank you . . this post now solved :)

Comment: OP (and partially @Marius). Please consider deleting the answer. It is considered a duplicate anyway. If you do not think it is a duplicate, then you could make a Q/A pair, by creating an answer instead of a comment. That would be more readable for people with the same question and be easier to ignore for readers looking for questions they can answer.